# Confusion with sigdelset() function

Tags: c, linux, signals

sigdelset() function is used to turn off a single bit. Here is its implementation:

```
    int
    sigdelset(sigset_t *set, int signo)  //signo is the signal number
    {
    *set &= ~(1 << (signo - 1)); // turn bit off 
    return(0);
    }
```

I can't understand this code. I think that a signal number looks like `0010`(in binary). But it seen not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing how the human brain imagines binary numbers and how we denote them in C.

First, there's no binary notation in standard C (however certain compilers accept `0b...` as an extension).

Second, `1 << (signo - 1)` is a binary left shift operator. Signo is probably the ordinal number of the bit to be turned off, starting from 1. Then we subtract 1 from it, thus we obtain a number starting from 0 (logically the first bit). Then we left shift it to obtain 2 to the power (signo - 1), which is a number of which the binary representation looks like this:

```
00000010000000... etc.
      ^
      +-  bit #signo - 1
```

Then the function uses the `~` (2's complement) operator which will result in (along with the bitwise and assignment operator, `&=`) turning the bit off.

Comment: @Nmzzz then the function is good, just see the other parts of my answer as an explanation :)

Comment: Could you explain more for `First, there's no binary notation in standard C (however certain compilers accept 0b... as an extension).`  @H2CO3

Comment: @Nmzzz in C, you can't write a number in base-2 directly, the standard only requires decimal and hex notation. However, certain compilers, such as GCC, support writing binary numbers directly such as `0b10010011100110`.

Comment: Thanks. It's very kind of you.  @H2CO3